# Better htaccess'ing?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Is there a more efficient way of doing the below? I can't find a clear solutions online.

Everything works, but I just got this feeling that it's the long way round.

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/item/([0-9\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/$  index.php?level1=$1&level2=$2&level3=$3&articleID=$4 [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/item/([0-9\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/$  index.php?level1=$1&level2=$2&level3=$3&articleID=$4 [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/item/([0-9\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/$  index.php?level1=$1&level2=$2&articleID=$3 [L]
```

If I want to add a mediaID possibility for each one, do I have to duplicate all 3 and then add `.../media/([0-9\-]+)/$` and `...&mediaID=$x`? A sample URL is `/directors/item/16/nicholas-barker/showreel/media/111/`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this. I have some problems to figure out want you want, but :

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)(?:/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)(?:/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+))?)?/item/([0-9\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/media/([0-9\-]+)/$ index.php?level1=$1&level2=$2&level3=$3&level4=$4&level5=$5&articleID=$6&articleSubId=$7&mediaID=$8 [L]
```

The variable that do not exist would be just empty. (You'll have to check this
in index.php). By the way your $x seems to be incoherent to me. You don't use the same parts of the URL for you article ID etc... So you have to tune them a bit in my expression (i've made strong assumption on your architecture.